# Only keep row that do not contain values in two columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to only keep row where COL1 does not contains ("Danio_rerio") and COL2 does not contains ("Homo_sapiens")

I used the following syntax:

```
df.loc[~ (df['COL1']=="Danio_rerio") & (df['COL2']=="Homo_sapiens")]
```

But it does not do what I want, am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here need `~` for both conditions, so added `()` - it means remove rows if match `"Danio_rerio"` and `Homo_sapiens`:

```
df.loc[~ ((df['COL1']=="Danio_rerio") & (df['COL2']=="Homo_sapiens"))]
```

Or use De morgans laws and invert `==` to `!=` and `&` to `|`:

```
df.loc[(df['COL1']!="Danio_rerio") | (df['COL2']!="Homo_sapiens")]
```

> Doesn't OP ask for both values shouldn't be in the respective columns?

It means remove rows if match `"Danio_rerio"` or `Homo_sapiens`:

```
df.loc[~ ((df['COL1']=="Danio_rerio") | (df['COL2']=="Homo_sapiens"))]

df.loc[(df['COL1']!="Danio_rerio") & (df['COL2']!="Homo_sapiens")]
```